# Updating fragment view after setting listAdapter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am converting an existing activity (SherlockActivity) into fragment (SherlockListFragment) in order to use tabs.

The fragment returns a onCreateView when created and is using the following code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);

    /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

}
```

That works fine but as I was doing in my activity I want to update the list view with my own content after I finish fetching it from the server.

```
ListView listContent = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.contentlist);    
listContent.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Whatever I have researched so far, I am fetching the listview through activity and setting my adapter to it but that is having no effect on fragment view and it remains the same.

Question is: How can I update listView from outside onCreateView?

Answer (score 0):

First, make your listview a global var. Then set its value on the onCreateView function:

```
ListView list;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_placelist, container, false);
    list = rootView.findViewById(/*your id*/)
     /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);

    /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
   setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

}

```
//change your listview content here when refresh or something else
public void updateListView(){
    List l = /*fetch new data from server*/
    listAdapter.addAll(l);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView list;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_placelist, container, false);
        list = rootView.findViewById(/*your id*/)
         /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
       setListAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
}
```

from here android versions must be a arraylist or string array or hashmap